# Handle WebApi Core methods with Id as string and int

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

I have two methods:

```
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public IActionResult GetTask([FromRoute] int id)
    {
    }

    [HttpGet("{userId}")]
    public IActionResult GetUserTask([FromRoute] string userId)
    {
    }
```

As you can see, i want to pass to my API routes like:

`https://localhost:44365/Task/1`

and

`https://localhost:44365/Task/string`

But my `WebApi` project cant handle it. When i pass route like this:

```
https://localhost:44365/Task/7dd2514618c4-4575b3b6f2e9731edd61
```

i get an `400 http` and this response:

```
{
"id": [
    "The value '7dd2514618c4-4575b3b6f2e9731edd61' is not valid."
]
}
```

While debugging, im not hitting any methods (when i pass string instead of int)

My question is, how to verload methods with one parameters with `string` or `int`? These methods do diffrent things

**EDIT**

When i pass something like:

```
https://localhost:44365/Task/dddd
```

I still get response with invalid `id`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define parameter type like `[HttpGet("{id:int}")]`. For more information refer below link.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#route-constraints

Your actions should be like below.

```
    [HttpGet("{id:int}")]
    public IActionResult GetTask([FromRoute] int id)
    {
    }

    [HttpGet("{userId}")]
    public IActionResult GetUserTask([FromRoute] string userId)
    {
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use like this

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
    public IActionResult GetTask([FromRoute] int id)
    {
    }

    [HttpGet("User/{userId}")]
    public IActionResult GetUserTask([FromRoute] string userId)
    {
    }
```

and while calling api with guid/string use

```
https://localhost:44365/Task/User/7dd2514618c4-4575b3b6f2e9731edd61
```

Comment: Yes i know i can do this, but there is solution to my case? I dont want to use special route for only one method in controller